# React component not appearing in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm having a problem with creating a React component with Typescript in a Chrome extension I'm creating.  I placed divs with id's in welcome.html that should make the React components show up.  Strangely, the first React component in welcome.html shows up (TabMenu), but the second one, Dropdown, doesn't show up.  Any help would be much appreciated!

welcome.html

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head> 
    <body>

        <div id="tabMenu"></div>

         <h2>Welcome!  Select your preferred citation format</h2>

        <div id="citeDropdown">Hello</div>

      <!-- Dependencies -->
        <script src="./node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="./node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

        <!-- Main -->
    <script src="./components2.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="interface.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { TabMenu } from "./reusable/TabMenu.tsx";
import { AccountFields } from "./reusable/AccountFields.tsx"
import { Dropdown } from "./reusable/Dropdown.tsx"

ReactDOM.render(
    <TabMenu compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
    document.getElementById("tabMenu")
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <AccountFields compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
    document.getElementById("accountFields")
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Dropdown compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
    document.getElementById("citeDropdown")
);
```

Dropdown.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface DropdownProps {compiler: string; framework: string;}

export class Dropdown extends React.Component<DropdownProps, undefined> {
    render() {
        console.log("in render");
        return (
          <div>
                <h1>Test header</h1>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: if you switch the citeDropdown with tabmenu whois rendered?

Comment: try to upload your code

Comment: If I switch them,  TabMenu is still rendered and citeDropdown isn't rendered

Comment: Don't guess: check the console for errors, debug your code. Note, the popup has its own devtools and console. Or you can open the popup in a tab using its full URL chrome-extension://your-extension-id/path-to-your-popup.html

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].